# CF update env variable

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm having application that pushed to CF which is working fine.

when I do cf env appName I got the section **User-Provided:**

in this section I see several of objects with values and I want to update new value to existing object, how I should do this ?

e.g.

when I use cf env

```
System-Provided:
....


User-Provided:

    SERVICES: []
    annotations: [
      {
        "name": "Book",
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
      }
    ]
```

And what I want is to change the **URL value inside the annotations** ...
I try with CF set-env but it create additional filed, I want to update existing field with the command line without the need to restart my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already pointed out, variables can be set and updated using the `cf set-env` command. The problem is in your case is that one of the variables, `annotations`, is a complex JSON object.

You would need to update `annotations` and provide the full, updated object:

```
cf set-env yourapp annotations '[{"name": "book", "url": "updated URL"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks I try it out and I got error FAILED
Incorrect Usage. Requires an argument

NAME:
   env - Show all env variables for an app

USAGE:
   cf env APP_NAME

ALIAS:
   e

Comment: I was able to do CF env myapp ...and when try like you tell cf env myapp annotations '[{"name": "book", "url": "updated URL"}]' , I got the above error ...

Comment: Sorry, I used "env" instead of "set-env" in the sample code